# Copy containing folder name in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, directory, sublimetext, copy-paste

How do i copy the containing folder name of currently opened file in Sublime text 3. i'm using windows 7.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Path%20Tools

Comment: This plugin retuns the full path of that directory. i need only the directory name.

Comment: Make your own plugin

Comment: i dont know how to build a package for sublime....

Answer (score 1):

- Right click in the body of the open file.
- Choose `Copy File Path` from the menu. This will give you the full file path to the file.
- Open a new empty file.
- Paste the full path into the new empty file.
- Use `Find and Replace` with RegEx enabled with the following:

  - **FIND** `.*/(.*)/.*`
  - **REPLACE** `$1`
- You now have the name of the folder containing the current file.

Obviously you can improve on this with automation and the like but since you report you don't have the skills currently this will work until you have the time free to devote to developing those new skills.